# Plone: can I make @@manage-portlets use a template other than main_template.pt?

Tags: plone

I have an alternate homepage template, homepage.pt, which has a different layout. When I click the manage-portlets link to edit the portlets, though, it uses main_template.pt instead of homepage.pt. Is there any way to have @@manage-portlets use whichever template the page you're editing the portlets for uses? It's workable as is, but the layout is quite different to what the page actually looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the answer is yes, with a little messing around. You can use an alternate template for manage-contextual.pt out of plone.app.portlets and change the metal:use-macro attribute to use your custom macro. I used jbot and naming the file:

plone.app.portlets.browser.templates.manage-contextual.pt

does what it should. This replaces the manage portlets view for all pages though, including ones that were using main_template.pt. Not insurmountable, but a little annoying. I can think of a few solutions:

1. Just add a new manage-portlets-yourspecialtemplate view that has a copy of manage-contextual.pt, modified to suit. This is the easiest way and lets me edit all my portlets (including the ones that were already there) in context as I originally wanted. Yay!
2. I didn't try it, but if the only page you have with a non-main_template.pt template is your homepage you could try registering a manage-portlets view for the Products.CMFPlone.interfaces.IPloneSiteRoot interface. I haven't tried adding views with the same name (but applying to different interfaces) so I have no idea if this works.
3. Some conditional logic in manage-contextual.pt that uses a different template based on whatever you use to distinguish whichever pages have different templates.

Answer (score 3):

We register another page for this purpose and register an portal_actions object action

zcml:

```
<browser:page
    for="plone.portlets.interfaces.ILocalPortletAssignable"
    class="plone.app.portlets.browser.manage.ManageContextualPortlets"
    name="manage-homepageportlets"
    template="templates/managehomepageportlets.pt"
    permission="plone.app.portlets.ManagePortlets" />
```

view:

```
class HomepageView(BrowserView):
    template = ViewPageTemplateFile('templates/homepage_view.pt')
```

action:

```
<object name="homepage portlets" meta_type="CMF Action">
   <property name="title">Homepage-portlets</property>
   <property name="url_expr">string:${portal_url}/@@manage-homepageportlets</property>
   <property name="available_expr">python: here.absolute_url() == portal_url</property>
   <property name="visible">True</property>
</object>
```

template:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:metal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/metal"
  xmlns:tal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/tal"
  xmlns:i18n="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/i18n"
  metal:use-macro="context/main_template/macros/master"
  i18n:domain="plone">

<body>
<div metal:fill-slot="main">
    <h1 class="documentFirstHeading">Manage Homepage Portlets</h1>
    <h2>Top portlets</h2>
    <span tal:replace="structure provider:project.homepagetop" />
    <h2>Middle portlets</h2>
    <span tal:replace="structure provider:project.homepagemiddle" />
    <h2>Bottom portlets</h2>
    <span tal:replace="structure provider:project.homepagebottom" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```